# Django filter by multipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I have model Skill

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    hero= models.ForeignKey(Hero)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

And I have model Hero

```
class Hero(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I use multiple choice field to select skills

```
OPTIONS = (
        ("sharingan", "sharingan"),
        ("rasengan", "rasengan"),
        ("fireball", "fireball"),
    )

    skills= forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                          choices=OPTIONS)
```

I use `get request` to send my form and my search page url becomes something like:

```
mysite.com/search?skills=shiringan&skills=rasengan
```

In my views.py I have

```
def vip(request):
    heroes = Hero.objects.all
    return render(request, 'app_name/search.html',{'heroes': heroes})
```

What should I write in `views.py` to select all heroes with chosen skills?

Comment: Why don't you use ManyToManyField instead?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `ManyToManyField` Instead.

like this:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Hero(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
```

and use forms like this:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Hero

class HeroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = '__all__'
```

and finally your views:

```
# views.py
from .models import Hero, Skill
from .forms import HeroForm

def my_heroes(request):
    heroes = Hero.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'heroes':heroes})

def hero_skill_select(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HeroForm(request.POST)
        # do something
    else:
        form = HeroForm()
    return render(request, 'template_with_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I have a question: right now I use a custom form, not a form for model. It is just better for this task. I build a form like this: `age = forms.ChoiceField(label="", choices=age, required=False)`  And in my `search.html` I include it like this: `{{ simple_search_form.age }}` Can I do the same with skills? Can I write something like `{{simple_search_form.skills}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the Hero model have Skill as foreignfield, rather than the opposite? I don't understand the logic behind your classes.

Based on your current Classes and their relationship, you could do something like this:

```
chosen_skills = Skill.objects.values('hero').distinct().annotate(skill='name', hero_name='hero__name')
```

Haven't tested it, but basically, for every distinct hero, it returns the skill and the name. Let me know if this helps.